# Getting error ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I tried to pass some string from a Controllers method to view but it is giving error
**ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass):**

These are my code's i tried:

ApplicationController.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
private
    def baconipsum
        @baconipsum ||= Faraday.new("https://baconipsum.com/") do |f|
          f.response :json
        end
      end
end
```

ArticlesController.rb

```
def show_Data
    #@count = params[:count]
    @bacon = baconipsum.get("api/", type: 'all-meat',paras: 2).body
end
```

_show_data.html.erb

```
<% @bacon.each do |meat| %>
  <p><%= meat %></p>
<%end%>
```

Here I tried to take user input that how many paragraph he wants  to generate and i will pass its value to controller show_data, so that Faraday will generate that number of paragraph for it

Here is my form view

_form_data.html.erb

```
<%= form_for:article do %>
    <label for="value">Value</label>
    <%= text_field_tag :value %>
    <%= submit_tag "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```rb
# config/routes.rb
get "articles/show_data", to: "articles#show_data"

# app/controllers/articles_controller.rb
def show_data
  @bacon = baconipsum.get("api/", type: 'all-meat',paras: 2).body
  # NOTE: this action will `render "show_data"` by default
end                                        # |
                                           # |
# app/views/articles/show_data.html.erb <----'
<% @bacon.each do |meat| %>
  <p><%= meat %></p>
<% end %>
```

To see the result, go to http://localhost:3000/articles/show_data

**Update**

```rb
# app/controllers/articles_controller.rb
def show_data
  @bacon = baconipsum.get("api/", type: 'all-meat',paras: 2).body
end

def show
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  show_data # this will set `@bacon` variable
end
```

```html
<!-- app/views/articles/_show_data.html.erb -->
<% bacon.each do |meat| %>
  <p><%= meat %></p>
<% end %>

<!-- app/views/articles/show.html.erb -->
<%= render "articles/show_data", bacon: @bacon %>
```

**Update 2**

Submit form to `ArticlesController#show` action:

```rb
<%= form_for :api_options, url: "/articles/1", method: :get do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :paras %>
  <%= f.text_field :paras %>

  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

`ArticlesController#show` calls `show_data` method. Submitted form parameters are available through `params` method in the controller:

```rb
def show_data
  @bacon = baconipsum.get(
    "api/",
    type: 'all-meat',
    # NOTE: use `fetch` method and set some defaults when params are not present.
    paras: params.fetch(:api_options, {}).fetch(:paras, 1)
  ).body
end
```

---

*https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#methods-and-actions*

*https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-by-default-convention-over-configuration-in-action*

Comment: I want to partial render the show_data.html.erb at http://localhost:3000/articles/2
where 2 is the id of article, for this I have changed the name of show_data.html.erb to _show_data.html.erb , but getting error (undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass):"

Comment: HEY, @Alex help me

Comment: According to you, it is working for articles/show_data but I want it to partial render it from articles/id

Comment: didn't we do this exact thing last time? if you don't call `show_data` method, `@bacon` is `nil`. if you go to `articles/1` it routes to `ArticlesController#show` which renders `show.html.erb`. somewhere along the line you have to set your variables, then render the partial from `show.html.erb`

Comment: Thanks a lot @Alex, I am little bit confused, and I will ask one more question to you....after some time....help their plzzzz

Comment: Hey alex, Kindly help me here please check this question.......

Comment: Hey @Alex, getting this error ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Article with 'id'=show): in terminal

Comment: just replace the url to what you need, like `articles_path(@article)`

Comment: <%= form_for :api_options, url: "/articles/2", method: :get do |f| %> , i did this but now its become specific for article having id = 2

Comment: it is working, just i have modified articles_path to article_path,  but can you make me understand"  form_for :api_options, url: article_path(@article), how it is working and what is api_options in form_for

Comment: And is there any generalised way so that i can direcltly pass the value without taking api_options??

Comment: help me please I am not getting it anywhere

Comment: looks like you got it working. what else can i do? your api is working, form is working. here is how you set up a generic form: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#a-generic-search-form

Comment: what this mean?  form_for :api_options

Comment: generic method i want to say that: here this type of URL is generating : http://localhost:3000/articles/2?api_options%5Bparas%5D=2&commit=Save insteand of this can we generate URL like http://localhost:3000/articles/2/paras = 2